# Django When(...) object SQL missing when used with __in lookup with empty list as value, leading to ProgrammingError

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

using Django 3.0 (will be upgraded) I get some invalid SQL that leads to a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError`, and I wonder if anyone can help me see why.

I wonder if this problem also occurs in newer versions of Django. But I hope to get it working without having to upgrade Django right away.

Querying a Model I am annotating a field to each instance, and using `Case` and `When` with that, and it seems that the error happens when using a negated `Q` object with a `__in` lookup that gets an empty list as value.

I will show three examples that are very similar, but lead to different SQL. Only the first example leads to erroneous SQL.

Example query that leads to invalid SQL:

```
Activity.objects.all()
.annotate(
    employee_authorized=Case(
        When(~Q(case__assigned_unit__in=[]), then=Value(False)),
        default=Value(True),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

This leads to the following SQL, where there's nothing in between `WHEN` and `THEN`. This results in a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError`.

```
SELECT "activity_activity"."id",
       ...
       CASE WHEN THEN False ELSE True END AS "employee_authorized"
FROM "activity_activity"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "case_case" ON ("activity_activity"."case_id" = "case_case"."id")
```

The below example seems to lead to logical SQL. The only difference being that the `Q` object is not negated.

```
Activity.objects.all()
.annotate(
    employee_authorized=Case(
        When(Q(case__assigned_unit__in=[]), then=Value(False)),
        default=Value(True),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

the SQL:

```
SELECT "activity_activity"."id",
       ...
       True AS "employee_authorized"
FROM "activity_activity"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "case_case" ON ("activity_activity"."case_id" = "case_case"."id")
```

Another example that does lead to logical SQL, while negating the `Q` object, but using a list that is not empty.

```
Activity.objects.all()
.annotate(
    employee_authorized=Case(
        When(~Q(case__assigned_unit__in=[OrgUnit.objects.first()]), then=Value(False)),then=Value(False)),
        default=Value(True),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

Which leads to the following SQL:

```
SELECT "activity_activity"."id",
       ...
       CASE
           WHEN NOT ("case_case"."assigned_unit_id" IN (251) AND "case_case"."assigned_unit_id" IS NOT NULL) THEN False
           ELSE True END AS "employee_authorized"
FROM "activity_activity"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "case_case" ON ("activity_activity"."case_id" = "case_case"."id")
```

So. I don't see what or if I am doing something wrong here. Hoping that someone can help me get this to work.

Comment: The SQL does look better when I do something weird like: `When(Q(id__isnull=False) & ~Q(case__assigned_unit__in=[]), then=Value(False))`

Comment: Some info here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15145

Answer (score 1):

One idea to avoid this happening is to "switch" the default condition and use Q() instead of ~Q()

```
.annotate(
    employee_authorized=Case(
        When(Q(case__assigned_unit__in=[]), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't know if that's possible with our situation. But combining the Q object with another one that's always true (like checking if id is not null) the resulting SQL seems right (am still writing out the tests for different situations before I dare to say I have the result I am looking for :))